# Objective C iOS project + Swift 2 WatchOS project with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, watchos

I've got an Objective-C project , and I recently added a WatchOS 2 project to it which is in Swift 2.

From WatchOS project ,I'm accessing an Objective-C class (lets just say `Equations.m`) via a bridging header. However this `Equations.m` file imports another library (to be specific `HHUnitConverter`) and this `HHUnitConverter` was added to the project using Cocoapods.

When I build the WatchOS project I'm getting this error : "`HHUnitConverter.h`" is not found.

Isn't it possible to use an Objective-C class via a bridging-header in a Swift class, when that Obj C class has references to another Obj-C classes that were added using cocoapods?  What should I change to make this file available to the compiler?

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get this working for hours, any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `HHUnitConverter` should be added to your WatchOS target as well from your Podfile. Can you paste your podfile here?

Comment: HHUnitConverter.h should be added to bridging header also if it is in Objective C

Comment: bridging header also gives an error if I try to import the HHUnitConverter.h into it. It says file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Select your watchOS target and go to Build Settings. Set the 'Objective-C Bridging Header' file to the same file as in your iOS target.